# Adding a button in group indicatior in expandablelistview does not expand list?

Tags: android

I have an app which contain a expandablelistview with default groupIndicator and some child items. What i want to add a toggle button on right side of group header but when i do that listview does not expand. Pls help me out from this porblem.

code:-

```
 @Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    WhiteListModel model = whiteListStorage.get(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.white_list_group_header, null);
    }
    TextView t = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    t.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    t.setText(model.getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

main activity xml:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#f4f4f4" >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lvExp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
```

group header xml:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="12dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="17dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:checked="true" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXSgU.png)

Comment: Share the listener code when switch is clicked.

Comment: Idid not made listener just added a toggle on right and then checked and found after adding toggle on right as group indication along with defaut indicator listview does not expand.

Comment: See i have added a image which i want to archeive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand the group using ExpandableListView.expandGroup(pos) in the switchCompat's listener method when switchcompat is is checked and call ExpandableListView.collapseGroup(pos) when it is unchecked.

Comment: No i don't want t expand on switch listner my problem is that on the left side of group header contain default indication and center containg group header and on right i have added a toggle. After doing all when i click listview it is not expanding.

Comment: Try adding android:focusable="false" in switchCompat.